# Вывод рубрик, и подсчёт количества товаров в них PHP+mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, меню

Здравствуйте.

У меня сейчас задача следующая.

```
| id | parent_id | cat_title | ... |
```

это таблица рубрик, рубрики бывают 1-го уровня и 2-го, глубже вложенности нет. По parent_id определяется, какая рубрика является родительской для данной.

```
| id | cat_id | item_title | ... |
```

это таблица товаров, принадлежность к рубрике определяется по cat_id.

Я выбираю все существующие (даже пустые) рубрики списком, и считаю, сколько товаров в каждой из них вот таким запросом:

```
SELECT cat.*, COUNT(item.id) AS count FROM cats_table cat LEFT JOIN items_table item ON cat.id = item.cat_id
```

Результат вывода примерно такой:

*Автомобили (0)*
*-- Субару (4)*
*-- Фиат (8)*
*Мотоциклы (3)*
*-- Кавасаки (14)*

Всё вроде в порядке, остался один вопрос - как в родительской категории подсчитать общее количмество товаров из подрубрик? В указанном примере должно быть по идее *Автомобили (12)* и *Мотоциклы (17)*

UPD Или может как-то обработать результат запроса надо? Потому, что я сколько ни курю мануалы, так и не нашёл как в самом запросе это сделать.

Спасибо всем откликнувшимся!